# Can an <object> tag resize when a <table> inside is rendered?

Tags: html, object, html-table, resize, autoresize

As you know, an HTML `<table>` element can have a lot of geometry variation for width and height of cells and the whole table overall.  The browser does a lot of work re-sizing cell height and width to fit "nicely." in the available window size.  A huge range of variation exists in table geometry, of course.

When an `<object>` contains an HTML `<table>`, that former tag can specify width="100%" (or some fixed pixel width), which render pretty well for nominal cases.  However if the table height as-rendered is rather large, setting height="100%" doesn't yield a very tall table, and it's not dynamic as the browser window changes.  And using fixed pixel height= is unhelpful if you don't know the as-rendered height in advance.  If you're relying on the browser to arrange the cells in its default behavior.

Does anyone know any tricks to get `<object>` to better respect the dimensions of an HTML `<table>` inside it?  I can picture the `<object>` inquiring its contents for height or width attributes on a root element, e.g. SVG markup has these and resizes the containing `<object>` smartly.  Would it help to fake out `<object>` by including these attributes in the `<table>` markup?  (I've tried, but no joy in limited attempts).

I wish `<object>` were smarter about this, but apparently it's not.

Answer (score 0):

No.

You can use a [seemless](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#attr-iframe-seamless) iframe instead (although this is a bleeding edge feature with limited browser support at present).

Comment: Tried a few things on that, and no joy.  It seemed like I might have to get into some Javascript extensions to alter the `<object>` attributes myself, by brute force.  Arghhh, unnecessarily complex, why can't the darn tag do that itself!!